# Using YouTube to sell cars

Tags: youtube

Say I have a car dealership with a website.

Is there any legal or YouTube usage issues in creating a YouTube profile and uploading videos of cars for sale, and putting car, dealership and website info/links in the video descriptions?

And does the same thing apply to Facebook and Vimeo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely fine to upload videos to YouTube for commercial purposes, with links to your site, etc.
From the YouTube TOS:
http://www.youtube.com/t/terms

**Prohibited commercial uses do not include:**

**- uploading an original video to YouTube, or maintaining an original channel on YouTube, to promote your business or artistic enterprise;**
 - showing YouTube videos through the Embeddable Player on an ad-enabled blog or website, subject to the advertising restrictions set forth above in Section 4.D; 
 - or any use that YouTube expressly authorizes in writing.

And given this: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=71011&hl=en-US, it appears to be fine even to embed those videos for commercial (non-ad) usage.

> We've updated our Terms of Use to
>   clarify what kinds of uses of the
>   website and the YouTube Embeddable
>   Player are permitted.
>
> **We don't want to
>   discourage you from putting the
>   occasional YouTube video in your blog
>   to comment on it or show your readers
>   a video that you like, even if you
>   have general-purpose ads somewhere on
>   your blog.**
>
> We will, however, enforce
>   our Terms of Use against, say, a
>   website that does nothing more than
>   aggregate a bunch of embedded YouTube
>   videos and intentionally tries to
>   generate ad revenue from them.

Vimeo however appears to be a different story:

> **Vimeo is intended for non-commercial use. By using the Site, you agree to abide by these Terms of Service.**

Facebook I believe is fine, as many of the largest brands in the world use it for promotion, such as Coca Cola and Pepsi - so I think yours would be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Vimeo, in fact, has stated that even having Google ads on your blog counts as commercial use. Very restrictive.